# Salted password error in extension module in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am using TYPO3 9 LTS. When I click on the extension module in the backend an error message of salted password is shown.

I have checked `PackageStates.php` file, there is no such extension.

Please see the attachment.

[image]

Comment: Saltedpassword merged to core, check out reference here: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.4/Deprecation-85833-ExtensionSaltedpasswordsMergedIntoCoreExtension.html

Comment: Did you upgrade your installation to TYPO3 9.5? Maybe there is another extension installed which has a requirement for `saltedpasswords`? This must be updated then.